# Converting a user inputted boolean search string into mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a database search field where I want the user to be able to input simple boolean logic and have that translated to a mySQL search string.

So for instance if the user inputs: `(php AND mysql) OR ajax`

I'd like to convert that to:

`((c.Skillset LIKE '%php%'  AND c.Skillset LIKE %mysql%) OR c.Skillset LIKE '%ajax%')`

Is there a fairly simple way of doing this? I'm having particular trouble coming up with a solution for the brackets, if it wasn't for that it would be quite straightforward.

Comment: How malicious do you expect users of this tool to be? I know that you should never design things for anything other than the worst users, but if it needs to tokenize/parse the string to verify that it is valid, that's a harder problem than just doing some preg_replaces.

Comment: Well I was planning on doing htmlspecialchars encode on what it assumes is the search items like 'ajax', 'mysql' and then anything else is written by the function by what it interprets the logic to be from the input, so no possibility for injection... I assume that would be fine because as I understand it, you can't be malicious by just arranging ands and ors and brackets in a search string

Comment: But `((((((php AND mysql) OR ajax` for example would not be a valid query. So matching up even numbers of parentheses which properly group terms adds some complexity.

Comment: Oh right yes I see your point, yes I'd do simple validation on the result of the string for that, shouldn't be a prob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following assumes you have some constant called SQL_PREFIX_STRING defined.

```
$string = '(php AND mysql) OR java';
preg_match_all('/[a-z]+/', $string, $skills); // puts the skills in an array
$skills = $skills[0]; // shift array to get the matching values
array_walk($skills, function (&$skill) {$skill = '%'.$skill.'%';}); // add wildcards to parameters

$query_string = preg_replace('/[a-z]+/', 'c.Skillset LIKE ?', $string); // create the ? parameters for the SQL string

$pdoStatement = $pdo->prepare(SQL_PREFIX_STRING.$sql); // prepare
$pdoStatement->execute($skills); // execute
```

Comment: The above is in no way meant to be "optimal", but it accomplishes what you want while providing some level of security. Additionally you could add a replace statement to remove any words or characters that you don't allow, such as "; DROP TABLE ..." from the $string variable before this chunk of code (best done with a whitelist).

Comment: Wonderful, I'm going to use this and modify it a bit to fit into my application. Thanks very much